# User input is being read as illegal numerical value in Python

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to:

1. find a list of files which has a size greater than X Mb (where X is 
   being read from user input) in a specific directory and
2. move them to another folder

For #1 this code works fine:

```
X = input("enter the file size X in Mb \n")

!find . -type f -size +$X"M"
```

however for #2, as soon as I add `-exec` command (as follows) to move these files to a different folder I get the error:

> find: -size: +M: illegal numeric value

Any idea?

```
!find . -type f -size +$X"M" -exec mv {} ~/tmp/trash/ \;
```

Comment: post some code please. Also, what python version are you using?

Comment: How are you calling those commands? e.g. `!find`

Comment: Pynchia, I have pasted the code above. Here's the Python version I have: Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

Comment: Peter, I am using iPython notebook. The commands are a mix of python+unix.